# Unmovable files in VS2010 project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've got a Visual Studio 2010 C++ project. Previously everything was working fine but now when I create new files, they have strange little arrows in the corners. I've checked and they are *not* links, the files are at the hard location referenced. I've been through the project file and settings and cannot determine what on earth the difference is between them and my normal, good files. However, when I try to move these files to re-organize my project, Visual Studio won't move them. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Here's (part of) the project file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="Interfaces\OS\OS.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="Interfaces\Render\Math\colour.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="Interfaces\Render\Math\Point.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="Interfaces\Render\Math\rectangle.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="Interfaces\Render\render.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="Implementations\OS\Windows\Context.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="Implementations\OS\Windows\Window.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="Implementations\OS\Windows\Windows.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="Implementations\Render\Direct3D9\Context.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="Implementations\Render\Direct3D9\Direct3D9.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="Implementations\Render\Direct3D9\Font.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="Implementations\Render\Direct3D9\Label.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="Implementations\Render\Direct3D9\Scene.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="Implementations\Render\Direct3D9\Sprite.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="Implementations\Render\Direct3D9\Texture.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="UI\Context.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="UI\Controls\Button.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="UI\Controls\Context.h"/>
    <ClInclude Include="UI\Division.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

As you can see, all of the header files are listed equally, but only some of them are unmovable.

Comment: This may be a stupid question... If you open the .vcproj file, how do these files included in the project? (That is, are you sure they hadn't been added through 'Add as link' in the Add Existing File dialog?

Comment: @xxbbcc: I used "Add New Item" just like all the other times, and they are listed as exactly the same in the project file.

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of the project file?

Comment: @PoweRoy: Unfortunately, as I previously indicated, there is nothing there to explain the problem.

Comment: @DeadMG, just being sure. Maybe we can spot something.

Comment: When you bring up the properties window (F4, I believe), what properties do you see there?

Comment: Pretty much nothing. File name, file type, hard path, relative path. It's all got the expected values for all the files.

Comment: Look for other occurrences of "UI\whatever.h" in the project file. There must be another tag that refers to it.

Comment: @Agnel: Nope. Those are the only references to the entire folder.

Comment: Could the file on disk itself be a shortcut ...and .lnk file? Guessing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, this is something special. The problem only occurs if the root folder is named "UI". All other folder names work as expected. Re-creating the folder and files has no effect, but if the root folder is not named "UI", then everything correct. Going to chalk this one up to a Visual Studio error.

Comment: Did you report it on Connect? I have to admit to a kind of morbid curiosity about how long it takes them to close, and whether it is WONTFIX or BYDESIGN

Comment: @jalf: Nah, I never report on Connect, it's a waste of time. Feel free to steal it and report it yourself, though, if you feel like being a masochist :P